# I have seen this but not sure what it means

Tags: javascript

I have been looking into some javascript code and noticed this not sure what it does and why you would use it

```
let reset = function(a, b){
    b || (b = something, b.somethingelse && (b.other = b.somethingelse)) //....
    //some other code underneath
}
```

if could help me understand that, that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is the minified version of this:

```
let reset = function(a, b) {
  if (!b) {
    b = something;
    if (b.somethingelse) {
      b.other = b.somethingelse;
    }
  }
  //some other code underneath
}
```

How about checking out http://www.jsnice.org/ which does a very good job of unminifying the code even with variable names

Comment: cheers I needed that, it worked very well

Comment: The other unminifiers like https://unminify.com/ or https://beautifier.io/  don't work very well as they only make it look nice, not bring back if statement and loops etc

Comment: I have seen those before and they don't work well, I will keep that in mind for next time

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance

Answer (score 2):

This is the minified version of:

```
let reset = function(a, b) {
  if (!b) {
    b = something;
    if (b.somethingelse) {
      b.other = b.somethingelse;
    }
  }
  //some other code underneath
}
```

The minified version (which depends on the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in combination with `||` and `&&` in place if `if` tests) is not readable at all, but it saves a few bytes when the script is sent over the internet to a user. When trying to figure out and debug code, best to read the *source*, not the minified version.